# Ways to not overload my Database, from using C# asp.net MVC Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

Here's the Situation,

A URL such as http://examplesite.com?serial=4131&database=10,20,30,40,50&mdnt=2016,04,20,7,59,53  (HTTP request)

Since,    `database = 10,20,30,40,50  in the URL`

I need to store the values 10  20 30 40 50 into my database somehow.

For my case,  this is how I stored my Database

```
id   data  date
1     10     20/04/2016 7:59:53 
2     20     20/04/2016 7:59:53 
3     30    20/04/2016 7:59:53 
4     40    20/04/2016 7:59:53 
5     50    20/04/2016 7:59:53
```

I have implemented an Async Task for the controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> get(String serial, String database, String mdnt)
```

and

I am storing it into my Database using a c# For loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < database.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                int find_int_id = database[i]; 
                                // Getting ready to store !                               
 var getting_limit_id = db.graph_limit.Where(a => a.siteuser.sitetoboards.serialboard == mserial && a.graph_data_type.serial_id == find_int_id).Select(a => a.id).FirstOrDefault();
 // Error checks                                
     var getting_limit_id = db.graph_limit.Where(a => a.siteuser.sitetoboards.serialboard == mserial && a.graph_data_type.serial_id == find_int_id).Select(a => a.id).FirstOrDefault();

if (getting_limit_id .equals(0)
{ 
// throw error
}
     var getting_limit_id_type = db.graph_limit.Where(a => a.siteuser.sitetoboards.serialboard == mserial && a.graph_data_type.serial_id == find_int_id).Select(a => a.type).FirstOrDefault();

if (getting_limit_id_type .equals(0)
{ 
// throw error
}


 // Storing the Data into database
    graphs to_graph_db = new graphs();
                        to_graph_db.graph_limit_id = getting_limit_id;
                                        to_graph_db.value = idvalues_double[i];
                                        to_graph_db.plotdate = date;
                                        db.graphs.Add(to_graph_db);
                                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();   
                                }
```

So in this code:

```
if i = 0 

stores 10  and db.saveChangesAsync 

i = 1 

stores 20  and db.saveChangesAsync 

i = 2 

stores 30 and db.saveChangesAsync 

i= 3
```

stores 40 and so on until the end..

I am using Async so I can process multiple thread requests or URL request in which it doesn't block.

Question is, can this be overload my azure SQL Database easily? Can my way of storing be improved and are there new ways to handle database overload or blocking?  Will this method of storing using a forloop overload my Database since I am calling my database a lot due to so many URLS at once ?

Sometimes I may receive many URLS at once.
1) http://examplesite.com?serial=4131&database=10,20,30,40,50&mdnt=2016,04,20,7,59,53

3) http://examplesite.com?serial=4131&database=10,20,30,40,50,60,70,&mdnt=2016,04,20,7,59,53

4) http://examplesite.com?serial=4131&database=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30&mdnt=2016,04,20,7,59,53

All the `database="......."`  values need to be stored. 
thanks!

Comment: Can you send the comma-separated database string to a stored procedure? There are lots of SQL splitString examples (Google it). Insert into table from splitString table-function would be the most cost-effective way to do it.